# Winform - Label Printing?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, printing, migradoc

I am working on an application in which I need to print labels ranging from 1"x3" up to 8"x10". The text and images that will be printed on the labels is defined in a xml file that contains all needed info including its location on the label as defined by the top-left xy coordinate. I do not want to preview the print job, just send it to the printer on command. My question is, what is the preferred method for doing this?

I have toyed around with 2 different methods.

Method one:
Reading the xml and locating the items on a form, creating an image of the form and then printing it. This works but it just seems a bit hokey?? I have to display the form for a second to create the image and I really do not want to do that.

Method two:
I have looked into using MigraDoc to create a label document and then sending it to the printer. This approach will create the form and send it to the printer without being displayed however, I do not see how I can locate the items within the document based on xy coordinates?? Maybe I have missed something here but everything seems to be section and paragraph driven.

What would be the best/easiest way to accomplish this?

Comment: `What would be the best/easiest way to accomplish this?` - by using current technologies such as WPF and leaving winforms behind you can easily do this in some 30 to 50 lines of code total (C# or VB.Net + XAML)

Comment: I hear you and I couldn't agree more however, winforms has been dictated in the this case.

Comment: "dictated"?? Ok.... then good luck. I feel sorry for you.

Comment: Funny, I came here looking for answers not sympathy, your trolling is invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re Method two:
With MigraDoc you can use TextFrames to position items using XY co-ordinates. Textframes can overlap and if you use this method it will be your responsibility to make sure that everything fits into the designated area.

The better way of using MigraDoc would be using tables and/or paragraphs with exact heigths or spacings. This however cannot be used easily with your approach of using XML files with co-ordinates as spacings would have to be relative to the previous item.

You can use PDFsharp to create a PDF file that draws everything at the right places. But printing could then be a problem - you can call Adobe Reader passing command-line arguments to print automatically, but you cannot set sophisticated printer options. If you create only few print jobs and manual intervention is not a problem, this could be an option (and the PDF files allow a visual check of the document before you print it).

Comment: Thanks for the response PDFsharp Team. The TextFrames did the trick and everything was working great... Then it came to my attention that I also have images that will be streamed from the xml! At first, I was like no problem but then I realized that the Section.AddImage method will only take a file path and not a stream. So, I found [this]http://forum.pdfsharp.net/viewtopic.php?p=4123. I made the suggested to changes, rebuilt the dll's, added it to my project and errors galore!! Might there be a fix for this or a dll whith this included? Thanks

Comment: It seems the "errors" are only warnings. 
Discussion continues here: http://forum.pdfsharp.net/viewtopic.php?p=7055#p7055

Answer (score 1):

You could use the functionality in the `System.Drawing` namespace to draw your text and images directly to a bitmap, so you don't have to display a form.

```
Dim bm As Bitmap = New Bitmap(200, 200)
Dim gr As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bm)

Dim img As Image = Image.FromFile("image.jpg")
gr.DrawImage(img, x, y)

Dim fn As Font = New Font("Comic Sans MS",72)
Dim solidBlack As SolidBrush = New SolidBrush(Color.Black)
gr.DrawString("My Picture", fn, solidBlack, x, y)
```

Then do what you want with the bitmap `bm`, save, print, whatever.

Some more examples, http://www.websupergoo.com/helppdf9net/source/4-examples/20-systemdrawing.htm

Edit:
I don't remeber exactly how I overcame the text quality problem when I last used this, but I did have this stuff set in my code.

```
gr.SmoothingMode = Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality
gr.TextRenderingHint = Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.SingleBitPerPixelGridFit
gr.CompositingQuality = Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighQuality
```

Comment: Thanks for the info Kratz, looks to be exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: I have played around a bit with both DrawString and TextRenderer.DrawText. The quality of the text is pretty poor. I have tried setting the Graphics.SmoothingMode but still not very clear. Any ideas on how can I go about increasing the resolution of the text?

Comment: I seem to remember having that issue when I used this. See my edits. I don't remember what fixed it, but I'm pretty sure I got around that text issue.